# Querying nested object from Apollo Client cache fails with "Can't find field [FIELD] on ROOT_QUERY object"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

My React client uses a query to retrieve all photos of an album with `albumId` of 1:

```
const GET_ALBUM_PHOTOS = gql`
  query($albumId: Int!) {
    photos(albumId: $albumId) {
      id
      src
      thumbnail
      ...
    }
  }
`;
```

When I open the Apollo Chrome Extension, I can see the cached records:

```
photos({"albumId":"1"}):
0:{"__ref":"PhotoType:6100"}
1:{"__ref":"PhotoType:1284"}
2:{"__ref":"PhotoType:2014"}
3:{"__ref":"PhotoType:2745"}
4:{"__ref":"PhotoType:2425"}
...
```

Now, when I click on one of the displayed photos, inside the clickhandler I obtain the `photoId` and, subsequently, I want to set a local field `isSelected` on the photo object to `true`.

I extended the PhotoType on the client side inside `resolvers.js`:

```
export const typeDefs = gql`
  extend type Query {
    ...
  }

  extend type Photo {
    isSelected: Boolean!
  }
`;
```

Inside the component which shows a grid of photos of a particular album, I try to retrieve the photo specified by its id like so:

```
      const obtainedPhotoId = 1089;

      const photo = client.readQuery({
        query: GET_PHOTO,
        variables: { photoId: obtainedPhotoId },
      });
```

where the `GET_PHOTO` query is defined as:

```
const GET_PHOTO = gql`
  query($photoId: Int!) {
    photo(id: $photoId) {
      id
      src
      thumbnail
      ...
    }
  }
`;
```

(As a side note, both queries work flawlessly on the server. I also have made sure that I don't forget the `variables` object.)

Now, the problem is that Apollo throws a MissingFieldError: `"Can't find field 'photo' on ROOT_QUERY object"`, which makes sense since the photo objects are inside the list with the key `photos({"albumId":"1"})`. From what I read on the docs and various comments on the issue tracker of the official repo, I probably need to define a cache-redirect. I tried this (among a lot of other things):

```
const iMCache = new InMemoryCache({
  addTypename: true,
  cacheRedirects: {
    Query: {
      photo: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) => {
        getCacheKey({ __typename: 'Photo', id: args.id });
      },
    },
  },
});
```

But the error persists unchanged. I also tried defining a resolver and adding it to the Apollo constructor:

```
  Photo: {
    isSelected: (photo, _, { cache }) => {
      const queryResult = cache.readQuery({
        query: GET_PHOTO,
        variables: { photoId: photo.id },
      });

      if (queryResult) {
        return queryResult.photo;
      }
      return false;
    },
  },
```

No change.

I'm not sure how to debug this since I stubbornly get the same error message, no matter how I change the resolver or the redirect. I also tried running the original query to retrieve the photos by album, the one which put these objects into the cache in the first place. Surprisingly, it tells me that it cannot find the query `posts`. The docs are relatively vage as there is no concrete example for this particular (yet supposedly very common) use case. What did I get wrong here?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that I'm using Apollo Client v3. After digging more into this, I think `CacheRedirects` is now obsolete and the way to go would be `typePolicies` but I still haven't found a way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

More fresh solution: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/#cache-redirects-using-field-policy-read-functions

Error points to missing `extend type Query { photo(photoId: ID!): Photo` - use "cach-only" fetch policy ... but it is a different approach to field policy.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go forward. However, with fieldPolicies I have the problem that it won't find "dangling" references of photo objects. I tried to use the keyFields feature so surface the objects to top-level (under a changed key) but it doesn't get picked up.

Comment: I tried extending the `Query` under `typeDefs` with `photo(photoId: Int!): Photo` but it still can't find the 'photo' field on the ROOT_QUERY object.

Comment: this https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/client-side-schema/ way?